# Heroku deployment fails silently on bower install

Tags: node.js, heroku, bower

I'm new to Heroku and find myself unable to deploy my app to Heroku (via Travis). My app is a JavaScript application and uses node / npm and bower to manage it's dependencies. My problem is that, on deployment, the app crashes immediately.

I *think* the problem happens in the `postinstall` hook in `package.json`, where I attempt to `bower install`.

I've enabled verbose logging which hasn't given me any insights into the problem

Firstly, my `package.json`, which is fairly standard:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "An AngularJS interface for The MovieDB",
  "repository": "https://github.com/....myrepo",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "start": "npm install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.15"
  }
}
```

And a standard `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.x",
    "angular-route": "1.4.x",
    "angular-loader": "1.4.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.x",
    "html5-boilerplate": "~4.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "holderjs": "~2.4.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.0",
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.7",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "font-awesome": "~4.4.0"
  }
}
```

And finally (and apologies for the size of this) the Heroku build log:

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]: npm verb cli   'start' ]
app[web.1]: npm info it worked if it ends with ok
app[web.1]: npm verb cli [ '/app/.heroku/node/bin/node',
app[web.1]: npm verb cli   '/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm',
app[web.1]: npm info using npm@2.14.4
app[web.1]: npm info using node@v4.1.2
app[web.1]: npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
app[web.1]: npm verb config Skipping project config: /app/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
app[web.1]: npm info start MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm info prestart MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: > MyApp@0.0.0 start /app
app[web.1]: > npm install
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: npm info it worked if it ends with ok
app[web.1]: npm verb cli [ '/app/.heroku/node/bin/node',
app[web.1]: npm verb cli   '/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm',
app[web.1]: npm verb cli   'install' ]
app[web.1]: npm info using npm@2.14.4
app[web.1]: npm info using node@v4.1.2
app[web.1]: npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from /app/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb config Skipping project config: /app/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
app[web.1]: npm verb install where, peers [ '/app', [] ]
app[web.1]: npm info preinstall MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from /app/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb targetResolver reading package data from /app/node_modules/http-server/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb targetResolver reading package data from /app/node_modules/.bin/bower/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb targetResolver reading package data from /app/node_modules/bower/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb targetResolver reading package data from /app/node_modules/.bin/http-server/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb already installed skipping http-server@^0.8.5 /app
app[web.1]: npm verb install where, deps [ '/app', [ 'bower', 'angular-ui-router', 'http-server' ] ]
app[web.1]: npm verb linkBins MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb rebuildBundles MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb installManyTop reading for lifecycle /app/package.json
app[web.1]: npm info build /app
app[web.1]: npm info install MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from /app/node_modules/bower/package.json
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from /app/node_modules/http-server/package.json
app[web.1]: > bower install
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: > MyApp@0.0.0 postinstall /app
app[web.1]: npm verb installManyTop reading scoped package data from /app/node_modules/angular-ui-router/package.json
app[web.1]: npm info linkStuff MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb linkMans MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm info package.json angular-ui-router@0.2.15 No license field.
app[web.1]: npm verb targetResolver reading package data from /app/node_modules/angular-ui-router/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb targetResolver reading package data from /app/node_modules/.bin/hs/package.json
app[web.1]: npm verb rebuildBundles [ '.bin', 'angular-ui-router', 'bower', 'http-server' ]
app[web.1]: npm verb already installed skipping bower@^1.5.3 /app
app[web.1]: npm verb already installed skipping angular-ui-router@^0.2.15 /app
app[web.1]: npm info postinstall MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
app[web.1]: npm verb validateInstall loading /app/package.json for validation
app[web.1]: npm info prepublish MyApp@0.0.0
app[web.1]: npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
app[web.1]: npm verb unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
app[web.1]: npm info ok 
app[web.1]: npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
app[web.1]: npm info ok 
app[web.1]: npm info poststart MyApp@0.0.0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```